# How to extend PasswordBroker in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-facade

I want to use my own PasswordBroker because the default one can't have its variable "emailView" modified after being initialized.

But I can't extend it in my custom class.

```
Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\MyPasswordBroker cannot
    extend from interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
```

This is my code:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker;


class MyPasswordBroker extends PasswordBroker {
    public function setEmailView($view) {
        $this->emailView = $view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

So what you'll want to do in this case is extend from the class, not the interface (Contract in Laravel-speak) and then bind that to the container. An implementation would look like follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker;

class MyPasswordBroker extends PasswordBroker 
{
    public function setEmailView($view) 
    {
        $this->emailView = $view;
    }
}
```

Then, in your `AppServiceProvider`'s `register` method, you would place

```
$this->app->bind(\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker::class, \App\Http\Controllers\Auth::class)
```

This will register your implementation to the contract, rather than Laravel's own implementation.

Comment: For the register part, it says `Cannot instantiate interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker`

Comment: Or maybe, do you know why it gives me `Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider] is not instantiable.` when I don't add to the register function of AppServiceProvider? I just want to use MyPasswordBroker in one very specific case and still keep using on the defaut PasswordBroker in the rest of the server.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `bind` not `register`. I've updated the answer to reflect that

Comment: I still have the `Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider] is not instantiable.`. Here is the log http://pastebin.com/ZVFjfDjr.

It seems that MyPasswordBroker can't correctly initiate because of the UserProvider from its construct parameters (which comes from PasswordBroker). But I'm not sure what I am supposed to do to make it work.

Comment: @BabyAzerty how are you attempting to access the password broker

Comment: I am using dependency injection on my Controller `public function __construct(MyPasswordBroker $passwords)` and there is a function in my Controller where I call `$this->passwords->setEmailView($path)` with $this->passwords being set in the construct function.

Comment: You should DI the contract not the implementation if you really wanna make use of it

Comment: I still get the `UserProvider` problem when I add `$this->app->bind(\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker::class, \App\Http\Controllers\Auth\MyPasswordBroker::class);` to AppServiceProvider and call `PasswordBroker` in DI of my controller

Comment: Well where is the user provider being used?

Comment: In the default PasswordBroker which I extend. I have the same code as you wrote. Not using explicitly UserProvider for this service.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "extend" an interface. An interface is just a constraint that says any class that inherits an interface will implement a set of functions. See [Interfaces and abstract class inheritance, implementation in extended classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369133/interfaces-and-abstract-class-inheritance-implementation-in-extended-classes) for further information.

What you really want is the implements keyword, so

```
class MyPasswordBroker implements PasswordBroker {
    public function setEmailView($view) {
        $this->emailView = $view;
    }
}
```

See https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Contracts/Auth/PasswordBroker.html for the list of functions you need to implement.

Comment: Just like with Phroggyy's answer, I get `Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider] is not instantiable.` when I use this implementation :/